# Deadlock in producer-consumer C programming

Tags: c, concurrency

I am trying to implement a single-producer-multi-consumer program in C, and I'm using the character '\0' in consumer to see whether it is the end of the file. However, deadlock occurs when when there are multi-consumer and when they all waiting for last character but only one of them entered critical section and consume this character. Here is my code:

```
void insert(char* buffer, char value){
    printf("lock in insert %c\n", value);     
    sem_wait(&empty);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    printf("insert %c\n",value);
    buffer[in] = value;
    in = (in+1) % BUFFER_SIZE; 
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full);
}
char get(char* buffer) {  
    char item;
    printf("lock in get\n");  

    sem_wait(&full);
    sem_wait(&mutex);      
    item = buffer[out];
    printf("comsume %c\n",item);
    out = (out+1)%BUFFER_SIZE;      
    sem_post(&mutex);  
    sem_post(&empty);  
    return item;  
}  
void *produce(void *param) {  
    int i=0; 
    char randomChar; 
    for(i=0; i<NUM_OF_INTEGERS; ++i) {
        randomChar = 'A' +random()%26;
        insert(buffer, randomChar);
    }
    insert(buffer, '\0');  
    printf("produce finished\n");  
}  

void *consume(void *param) {  
    int i=0;
    char data;  
    do{ 
        data = get(buffer);    
    }while(data != '\0');
    printf("consume finished\n");    
}
```

Comment: Producer/Consumer models queue concurrent access. Please read about the definition of the problem. You just use a fixed buffer concurrently filled and read, but not as a queuing system. Anyway, you need to define how you stops.

Comment: Your design is fundamentally flawed. You need to have a separate end marker for the message to each consumer. You can't have just one end marker for everyone, because only one consumer can read itg.

Comment: I understand I'm not using a queueing system, but the thing is even I changed it to a queue instead of an array, the deadlock still exists, how to define a end marker for everyone?

Comment: Consider using the atomic types in the standard library, with release and consume memory ordering?

Comment: For avoiding concurrency, I will suggest to use one semaphore variable.
Basically your critical code section is where `buffer` is accessed. Try to implement using one semaphore variable.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with one semaphore since the buffer is bonded and I need to check whether it is full before producer produces and whether it is empty before consumers consume, isn't it?

Comment: @pousT I think, the synchronization that you performed between 1 Producer and multiple consumer is not correct. Because in your logic, at most 2 consumers would be stuck in get function in spite of producer completion.

you should perform conditional variable along with mutex too. out variable should be local for each thread.  

besides this you can use multiple reader and writer lock.

Comment: @SumitGemini I'm not sure whether I get your point, but I can't see why out should be local since all threads are reading a shared buffer. As others mentioned, put end markers for each thread is a solution, I also come up another solution that add a if...else statement inside critical section, if the character is '\0' then it won't consume and post semaphore full, this also works.

Comment: @pousT what should be logic if 3 consumer are here? Should they not get same data as producer produce? To keep  insert(buffer, '\0') in a loop as a end marker means insert function will call sem_post() function. Because other thread still stuck in get() function waiting for lock.

Comment: @SumitGemini Consume means taking away data from buffer, which means only one consumer can access it.

Comment: @pousT if producer produce 'A' so all consumer should consume 'A'. What I understand about synchronization means. Means all threads should be in sync.

Comment: @SumitGemini please read the definition of producer/consumer problem

Comment: @pousT oops, i was wrong over producer and many consumer problem. i thought each customer will get what producer provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to send more than one terminator (i.e.) one for each consumer.

In `produce`, change:

```
insert(buffer, '\0');
```

Into:

```
for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_CONSUMER; ++i)
    insert(buffer, '\0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation fault can occur.

`buffer` size is of 10 Bytes and you are actually storing 20 Bytes.

Change `buffer` size to 20

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20
```

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that I should use out = (out+1)%BUFFER_SIZE instead of  out = (out+1)%NUM_OF_INTEGER to determine the position in buffer